# how to merge a list of strings with numpy arrays stored in a list

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, merge, concatenation

I have a list of numpy arrays and a list of strings. I want to merge strings with the arrays. These are my arrays and strings:

```
arrs=[np.array([[1.,0.,0.], [1.,1.,1.]]), np.array([[4.,4.,4.], [2.,4.,0.]]),\
       np.array([[9.,0.,9.], [9.,7.,5.]])]
names=['group_A', 'group_B', 'group_H']
```

First string in `names` should be added as the last column of first array in `arrs`. Second one also merges with second array and so on. Finally, I want to merge all the arrays ans get it as:

```
merged_arrs=[np.array([[1.,0.,0., 'group_A'], [1.,1.,1., 'group_A'],\
                       [4.,4.,4., 'group_B'], [2.,4.,0., 'group_B'],\
                       [9.,0.,9., 'group_H'], [9.,7.,5., 'group_H']])]
```

I have no idea how to concatenate these strings with arrays in python and do appreciate any help in advance.

Comment: I'd be sure this is really what you want to do. Once your numpy arrays have mixed dtypes, it's not very easy to work with them.

Comment: Dear @erip, Thanks for your hint. So, is it possible to for example firstly concatenate all the arrays and then strat to add each string two times (`len of concatenated array / len (names)`)?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Again, you get no benefit from mixing the dtypes in your np arrays. It seems like you might want a dataframe or similar.

Comment: You could use a recarray or so, but again, it seems that you fundamentally have an XY problem and are likely using the wrong tool for the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about we start with lists first, then convert each sub list into `np.array` later? I don't know why you need `np.array` instead of using built-in lists, but setting `dtype='object'` in `np.array` allows you to store items with different types.

##### Example Code

```py
import numpy as np

arrs = [np.array([[1., 0., 0.], [1., 1., 1.]]),
        np.array([[4., 4., 4.], [2., 4., 0.]]),
        np.array([[9., 0., 9.], [9., 7., 5.]])]

# Convert each sub array into list
arrs = [A.tolist() for A in arrs]

names = ['group_A', 'group_B', 'group_H']

for A, name in zip(arrs, names):
    for A_sub in A:
        A_sub.append(name)

# Convert each sub array into numpy array
merged_arrs = [np.array(A, dtype='object') for A in arrs]

print(merged_arrs)

# Outputs:
# [array([[1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 'group_A'], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 'group_A']], dtype=object), 
#  array([[4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 'group_B'], [2.0, 4.0, 0.0, 'group_B']], dtype=object), 
#  array([[9.0, 0.0, 9.0, 'group_H'], [9.0, 7.0, 5.0, 'group_H']], dtype=object)]
```

##### Reference

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.dtypes.html#specifying-and-constructing-data-types